# What does the `is` operator do in C#?

Tags: c#, operators

What does the `is` operator do in C#?

Comment: AFAIK There isn't such an *IS* operator in C#, but *is*, C# is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "is" operator takes 2 operands and returns a boolean value representing the ability for the first operand to be cast into the second operand. For example:

```
if(object1 is ClassA) //returns true if object1 is derived from ClassA or can be cast into ClassA.
```

Comment: You made a mistake in the code comment. "object1 can be cast into ClassA" doesn't mean "object1 is ClassA".

Comment: That's how I check for casting availability. if (someObject is someClass) then I can cast (someClass)someObject.

Comment: But in the comment, you said: if (can cast) then (object1 is ClassA), which is not correct.

Comment: @Smartest, Yes definitely the process isn't reversible and I didn't mean that. You understood it the wrong way.

Comment: well, it's not that it IS ClassA, but it could be, or is derived from, which means it technically IS ClassA (but maybe more)

Answer (score 4):

> An is expression evaluates to true if
>   the provided expression is non-null,
>   and the provided object can be cast to
>   the provided type without causing an
>   exception to be thrown.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw(v=vs.80).aspx